# How to get the selected radio button label text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a radio button like this on page

```
<div id="someId">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input name="x" type="radio" onchange="GetSelectedVal();">Yes</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input name="x" type="radio" onchange="GetSelectedVal();">No</label>
</div>
```

On page load I don't want to set any selection so not using `checked` property. In my JavaScript function, how can I get the value `Yes` or `No` based on the user selection at runtime?

```
function GetSelectedVal() {
    console.log($('#someId input:radio.........);
}
```

I have seen similar questions but unable to find solution of this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `onchange` inline handler from `HTML`. Use `on` to bind events.

`:checked` will select the `checked` radio button. `closest` will select the parent `label` and `text()` will get the label associated with the radio button. e.g. Yes

```
$('[name="x"]').on('change', function () {

    alert($('[name="x"]:checked').closest('label').text());

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7yxwm4zr/)

Comment: @Mivaweb Added explanation

Comment: @Mivaweb Wrong choice of words, check updated answer

Comment: @Learner plz check updated answer and I have added demo

Answer (score 2):

You can simple pass `this` in `onchange="GetSelectedVal();` like `onchange="GetSelectedVal(this);`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someId">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input  name="x" type="radio" onchange="GetSelectedVal(this);">Yes</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input  name="x" type="radio" onchange="GetSelectedVal(this);">No</label>
    </div>
<script>
function GetSelectedVal(ele) {
       alert($(ele).closest('label').text());
   }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it a bit different than the accepted answer.

Instead of having events on multiple radio buttons, you can have one on the containing div. Also let just the checked radio trigger the change:

```
$('#someId').on('change', 'input[name="x"]:checked', function () {
    var label = $(this).siblings('span').text();
    console.log(label);
});
```

When I have text next to other elements I prefer wrapping the text in span's:

```
<div id="someId">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input  name="x" type="radio"><span>Yes</span></label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input  name="x" type="radio"><span>No</span></label>
</div>
```

A demo: [jsfiddle.net/qcxgwe66/](http://jsfiddle.net/qcxgwe66/)