# Get the text of the selected radio button in JQuery

Tags: jquery

In Jquery How do I get the text (not values) for the selected radio button as shown below

```
 <label> <input type="radio" name="Surv_Q1" value="20">5 - Excellent</label>
<label> <input type="radio" name="Surv_Q1" value="20">4 - Good</label>
```

I tried with the below code , but didn't work

```
 $("input[name='Surv_Q"+i+"']:checked").next('label').text();
```

Comment: You can put those text on radio button's attribute like data-name="5 - Excellent" and use it like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the selected radio button label text using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072326/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-label-text-using-jquery)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<label> <input type="radio" name="Surv_Q1" value="20" data-name="5 - Excellent" checked="true">5 - Excellent</label>
<label> <input type="radio" name="Surv_Q1" value="20" data-name="4 - Good">4 - Good</label>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$("input[name='Surv_Q1']:checked").data('name');
```

**OR you don't want to change in HTML then this one::**

```
$("input[name='Surv_Q1']:checked").parent('label').text();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to travel up one level, to get the parent `label`:

```
$("input[name='Surv_Q1']:checked").parent('label').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone out... In my case I used `prev` instead of `parent` to get this to work:

```
$('input[name="radioName"]:checked').prev('label').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do it with this. (In some case leave parent like following)

```
$('input[name="selectorName"]:checked').parent().text();
```