# Am I able to get the text of a radio button in html to use in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, python-requests, radio-button

I'm working on a simple web application that lets users rate and comment on movies, storing them in a database to be viewed later. The user inputs a movie to rate, and if that movie title is shared by multiple films, they are prompted to specify which of those films they meant. I've chosen to do this with radio buttons in my html file, but I can't figure out how to get the text of the button chosen and use it in Flask. The application takes the name of the film chosen and prints that name at the top of a different html file, but no matter what I do it always prints "None" instead of the chosen title.

I was able to find this answer: [Get the text of the selected radio button in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42093490/13731647) , which led me to try

```
var confirmed = $("input[name='confirmation']:checked").parent('label').text();
```

in my html script in order to obtain the text of the checked button. But when I try to request this in Flask it does not work.

confirm.html :

```
<div id="id02" class="modal" data-backdrop="false">

    <form class="modal-content animate" action="/confirm" method="post">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Please Specify Which Title to Rate:</h1>

            {% for movie in multi %}
                <label class="container">{{movie["title"]}} ({{movie["year"]}})
                  <input type="radio" id={{movie["year"]}} name="confirmation">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            {% endfor %}

            <button type="submit">Rate</button>
        </div>

        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal when page is loaded 

    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#id02').modal('show');
    });
    
    var modal = document.getElementById('id02');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
  
  // variable storing the name of the film selected   
   var confirmed = $("input[name='confirmation']:checked").parent('label').text();
    
</script>
```

application.py :

```
@app.route("/confirm", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def confirm():

if request.method == "POST":
    
    full = request.form.get("confirmed")
    
    session["title"] = full # add movie title to session in order to use in rate function

    return render_template("rate.html", full=full)

else:
    
    return render_template("confirm.html")
```

I also have tried assigning an id to the button if it is checked in hopes of getting the text from the id, but when I tried this I just got "None" as well.

```
           {% for movie in multi %}
                <label class="container">{{movie["title"]}} ({{movie["year"]}})
                  <input type="radio" name="confirmation">
                    {% if checked=="checked" %}
                        <input type="hidden" id="confirmed" value="({{movie["year"]}})">
                    {% endif %}
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            {% endfor %}
```

I'm very new to programming and this is my first time trying to make a web application, so any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When flask gives you a radio button value. It gives you the value attribute not the radio button text, so you only need to put value attributes to your radio buttons